# Is it ok to use a 'boolean operator' to evaluate null in PHP

Tags: php

Is it ok to use a 'boolean operator' to evaluate null? ie

```
function a(bool $z): ?int 
{
    return ($z) ? 1 : null;
}

if (!$b = a(false)) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

It seems ok since $b will evaluate false if a returns null but it also seems wonky and like a potential source of errors. Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I remembered what I was looking for:

```
if (null === $b = a(false)) { ... }
```

It's a strange but elegant construct. Sorry if the intent wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: In my opinion this is messy code. It is hard to read. I consider even my code to be messy. It is better (easier to read) to add one more line of code like @Kita did than to pass all these arguments including the call to the function to the `if` statement.

Comment: It definitely will take some getting used to. It is concise, and I think once I start using it, it will not be hard to understand whenever I come across it. I've seen it used in php.net documentation, and always thought it was tricky and pretty cool. Very similar to the test for a boolean if (!$b = a(false)) ...

Comment: Concise sometimes has it's price. This time it is poor readability. If I had to choose between concise and readability I would always choose readability. This is just my opinion. But if this is a team project I would suggest readability.

Comment: I got this code from @Rasmus fwiw, which should be a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use triple equal (`===`) to compare value and *type*.

```
if(0 == null) { /* pass */ }

if(0 === null) { /* no pass */ }
```

Btw, did you intentionally assign `$b`'s value in the if condition?
Assuming you did not, the following if condition will distinguish `null`:

```
$b = a(false);
if($b === null) { ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes to the question. I'm trying to avoid the extra line of code in your last example. I agree that that is the less hokey way to go, but is there one that does it on one line?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `is_null`

Here is the test case :

```
<?php
  use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

  class BooleanTest extends TestCase
  {

     public function booleanProvider()
     {
        return [
            'boolean null' => [null, 'this is null boolean'],
            'boolean 0' => [0, 0],
            'boolean 1' => [1, 1],
        ];
      }

    /**
     * @dataProvider booleanProvider
     */
     public function testNullBoolean($value, $expected) {
        $actual = is_null($value) ? 'this is null boolean' : $value;
        $this->assertSame($actual, $expected);
     }
  }
```

I think the best way to find out if your code contains any potential error is to write the unit test for it, you could see many input and output for your code and find out where the errors could be.
Here is the phpUnit link [PhpUnit document](https://phpunit.de)

Comment: Thanks. Too lazy to test :). is_null is equivalent to == null, which may be fine, or === null may be better, but how do you construct it in one line of code?

Comment: Your question is to know whether the value is null or not, so `is_null($b)` is enough. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Comment: Sorry, I probably need to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP built in `empty()` method:

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.

The following values are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)

You can find more on the `empty()` method here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

---

So you could then write your function like this:

```
function a($var)
{
   return empty($var);
}

if( $b = a(false) )
{
   echo 'it is empty';
}
else
{
   echo 'it is not';
}
```

will output:

```
it is empty
```